# How do I integrate a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, calculus

I want to perform integration on a vector `L` but I don't know exactly what to use. I want to obtain `a` (the integral) as a vector that is the same size as `NT`.

```
clc;clear; 
syms x 
NT=input('NT='); 
L=zeros(NT,1); 
for i=1:NT 
disp('Longeur de travée') 
L(i)=input('L = '); 
L(i)=L(i); 
fa(i)=L(i).*x^2; 
a(i)=int(fa) 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to use trapz. If you have X and Y such that Y(i) = f(X(i)) (so Y contains the values of some function at the location X) then you simply do

```
I = trapz(X, Y)
```

In your case, you can do

```
I = trapz(L, fa)
```

I guess, looking at your code.

---

Note that you could use more advanced techniques, that will, in principle, give you a better result (because they are higher-order). This is just one method, but an easy one.